# Preparation of dihydroxyacetone phosphate from glycerine by fermentation

Tags: biochemistry, organic-chemistry, fermentation

I read on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihydroxyacetone) that
dihydroxyacetone (DHA) can be obtained from fermentation of glycerin. I would like to obtain dihydydroxyacetone phosphate (DHAP) for a science experiment but, since I'm 15, I cannot purchase it.

So I'm gonna have to make some if I want it.

With that being said, how do I properly ferment it, and how do I phosphorylate it? (I have phosphoric acid at home, maybe that would do the trick...)

Comment: I'm not convinced DHAP is easy to obtain by a fermentative process: it's an intermediary of glycolysis, so it's probably not accumulated.